# CentOS 5.3 Installed on INTEL all files show as AMD

Tags: centos, installation, intel

Random possible issue I can't seem to find a quick answer too. I've installed CentOS 5.3 on an Intel Xeon system, however all installed binaries show AMD arch along with all custom source bins showing AMD --- I am having strange issues and I'm wondering if anybody else has come across this or know if this is something I can safely ignore ---

Example:
swapon:                        ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
sysctl:                        ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
syslogd:                       ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped

Thanks - MG

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to ignore this - this is simply how CentOS labels its 64-bit packages, which work on both AMD and Intel processors that are 64-bit capable.

Any quirky behavior would not be caused by this - there are no AMD or Intel specific packages in any Linux distribution, as far as I'm aware; just 32 or 64 bit

Comment: +1, quite correct.  Some versions of linux identify the CPU architecture in this misleading manner, as x86-64 was actually created by AMD so presumably the identification dates back to times before Intel had this architecture available.

Comment: Agreed, but it's not "misleading", any more than calling the x86 architecture an intel architecture is misleading, when there are plenty of clones.

Answer (score 1):

Intel's 64-bit architecture (Itanium or IA-64) didn't really take off, but AMD's (amd64 or x86-64 or simply x64) did, so mainstream Intel 64-bit processors like the Core-2 series have it now too.  Hence, most 64-bit linux distros acknowledge the origin of the architecture and call it amd64.

Comment: Thanks guys -- great information --- I've never worked with CentOS distro before and this is the first time I have come across this.

Cheers -- alright -- back to debugging I go.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas ignore that and from INTEL only process 64bit IA-64 Itanium and other process from intel 64EM and centos copy the same version from RHEL same of the .rpm they change so its ok.